# How to create a actual versus target performance graph

Tags: reporting, forecast

I want to be able to measure the month on month number of users actual registrations to date vs. budget. How can I build a report and show a graph with the actual vs. the budget month on month for the year.
e.g., Jan 2014 actual to date 20,000 budget 21,000; Feb 2014 actual to date 20,100 budget 21,500; March 2014 budget 22,000

Answer (score 1):

Try this Answer in the Success Community: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hs6gAAA

Comment: please explain your answer in detail and give external links for references.